# Add Relativelayout or listview in Gallery in android?

Tags: android, layout, gallery

I will like to use gallery view to add listview or relativelayout. Most of the examples that I have seen are of adding images in gallery and that is quite simple. Can someone let me know how to add other layouts inside gallery view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add an Adapter that creates each View dynamically in the `getView()` method.

So you can create a RelativeLayout like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(ctx);
```

and then add children as you like.

Comment: Do you know if the layout can also be inflated from xml iinstead of just instantiating in code? Or must it always be instantiated? I'm having trouble getting the layout that's inflated to attach itself to the gallery using my adapter...

Comment: Yes, you can also use a LayoutInflater.